# Is there a way to run two programs simultaneously in C and records the output

Tags: c, dictionary, compilation, runtime

I have two programs in C almost the same (with a little different) and I have (key/value) dictionary in another C file

The following steps are done for both programs

compile the first program

```
gcc file1.c dict.c
```

compile the second program

```
gcc file2.c dict.c
```

and inside the file.c I called both functions update(to fill the dictionary) and printDic (to print the content of dictionary)

```
//file1.c
int func(int w){
  update("w",w) 
  if ((w >= w) && ((w % w) == 0))
  {
    w= w*4
    update("w",w) 
    printDic();
  }
  else
  { 
    w=1;
    update("w",w) 
    printDic();
  }
  return 0; }

//file2.c
int func(int w){
  update("w",w) 
  if ((w >= 4) && ((w / w) == 0))
  {
    w = w/2;
    update("w",w)
    printDic();

  }
  else
  { 
    w=0;
    update("w",w)
    printDic();
  }
  return 0; }
```

and both files have the same main

```
//main
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     func(10);
     func(5);
     func(2);
     func(0);
     func(180);

    return 0; }
```

So, the update() will fill the dictionary with the values of w once they change and then print them.

Is there a way to run these two files with the dictionary at once, in order to compare the output e.g. if I pass 10 in both programs will end up with a different value of w (which is stored in the dictionary).

Note: I need to call the func many times and in the same file I don't want to run the program each time with only one call.

the dictionary is working very well with one file and in each call to func the value of w is append to txt file.

Comment: Any reason you can't merge the two into a single program?

Comment: Running two different programs concurrently is a feature provided (or not) by your operating system.  All modern, general-purpose operating systems do provide for it, but available mechanisms vary.  But if you have more specific requirements, such as that the two programs share dictionary data, then that's more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the threading to achieve your goal, for example:

```
#include "pthread.h"                                                                                    
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                      

#define bool int                                                                                        
#define true 1                                                                                          
#define false 0                                                                                         
#define thread pthread_t                                                                                
#define thread_fire pthread_create                                                                      
#define thread_wait pthread_exit                                                                        

int get_mul(int num, bool even)                                                                         
{                                                                                                       
    if (even)                                                                                           
        return (2 * num);                                                                               
    else                                                                                                
        return ((2 * num) + 1);                                                                         
}                                                                                                       

void* func_odd(void *arg)                                                                               
{                                                                                                       
    int num =  *((int *)arg);                                                                           
    printf("%s: [%d]\n", __func__, get_mul(num, false));                                                

    return NULL;                                                                                        
}                                                                                                       

void* func_even(void *arg)                                                                              
{                                                                                                       
    int num = *((int *)arg);                                                                            
    printf("%s: [%d]\n", __func__, get_mul(num, true));                                                 

    return NULL;                                                                                        
}                                                                                                       

void func(int num)                                                                                      
{                                                                                                       
    thread tid;                                                                                         
    thread_fire(&tid, NULL, func_odd,  (void *)&num);                                                   
    thread_fire(&tid, NULL, func_even, (void *)&num);                                                   
    thread_wait(NULL);                                                                                  
}                                                                                                       

int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                                         
{                                                                                                       
    int i, num = atoi(argv[1]);                                                                         

    func(num);                                                                                          

    return 0;                                                                                           
}

**compiling:**
gcc -g -c thread.c
gcc -o thread thread.o -lpthread

**Output:**
./thread 3 
func_odd: [7]
func_even: [6]
```

In above example, replace func_odd() and func_even() with your two functions (with same name) defined in two different files.

For example, you can call "func_odd" to "func_file1", and "fund_even" to "func_file2".

Power of multithreading!!!!

Comment: Please mark as the answer and close the question if no further question/concern.